# PySimpleGUI Forms

Tags: python, forms, user-interface, pysimplegui

I am currently trying to do a simple form for a Loan application using PySimpleGUI and want to do calculations form the inputs i get from my form.

I have a couple of questions:-

1. Like the input() function, are the inputs on a form, strings?
2. if they are, how do i convert them to integers?

below is my current code for creating a basic form. As always your help is very much appreciated.

## Loan Form Creation

```
age = [(sg.Text("Please enter your age: "))], [sg.InputText()] 
month_income = [(sg.Text("Please enter your total monthly income after tax:"))], [sg.InputText()] 
month_expend = [(sg.Text("Please enter your total monthly expenditure: "))],[sg.InputText()] 
loan_amount = [(sg.Text("Enter the amount you would like to loan: "))],[sg.InputText()],[sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]

layout = [age, month_income, month_expend, loan_amount]

window = sg.Window('Loan Application', layout)
```

I have tried converting using the int() or float() functions but they don't work. I need them to convert so I can do calculations

Comment: `sg.Input` is fundamentally different from Python `input()`.  It is not a simple function returning a string that you then convert to other types as required. I suggest you check out the many demonstration code samples for example [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/user-input-in-pysimplegui/) and [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pysimplegui/pysimplegui_input_element.htm). There are also youtube videos including creating a form. You need to understand how `values` are accessed after calling `window.read()`.

Comment: You will likely end up with code that has a line of code like this.... `month_income = int(values['-MONTH KEY-'])`  .  The example from Jason is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

Need an event loop to process any event on the GUI, like events from keyboard or mouse.

Example Code:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def string_to_integer(string):
    try:
        result = int(string)
    except ValueError:
        result = None
    return result

entries = ["Age", "Monthly income after tax", "Monthly expenditure", "Anticipated loan"]
layout = [
    [sg.Text(entry), sg.Push(), sg.Input(key=entry)] for entry in entries] + [
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button("SUBMIT"), sg.Button("CANCEL")],
    [sg.Text("", relief=sg.RELIEF_SUNKEN, expand_x=True, key="STATUS")],
]
window = sg.Window('Loan Application', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, "CANCEL"):
        break

    elif event == "SUBMIT":
        result = age, income, expend, loan = tuple(map(string_to_integer, (values[entry] for entry in entries)))
        message = f"All the entries are integer and they are {result}" if all(map(lambda x:x is not None, result)) else "Wrong entries, all numbers should be in integer !"
        window["STATUS"].update(message)

window.close()
```

[image]

To simplify the code, without using the `map`, you can do it like

```py
    elif event == "SUBMIT":
        result = []
        for entry in entries:
            string = values[entry]
            result.append(string_to_integer(string))
        if None in result:
            message = "Wrong entries, all numbers should be in integer !"
        else:
            message = f"All the entries are integer and they are {result}"
        window["STATUS"].update(message)
```

Comment: Maybe simplify the code some by not using `map`?  Complete beginners will struggle to pick apart that line of code that's key to the entire point you're making.  More code is less confusion in this case?  Just a thought.... ;-)

Comment: Updated as above.